# Breeze navigation properties not being created in Json object

Tags: breeze

I have a product object called product which has a self referencing relationship so I can have parent products with child products. However although these are being created in the metadata and the lookup, breeze on the client is not creating them, they are always undefined.

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{

    ... properties removed ...
public virtual ICollection<Product> PackContents { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Product> PackParents { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent configuration:

```
        HasMany(a => a.PackContents).WithMany(b => b.PackParents).Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("PackProducts");
            m.MapLeftKey("ParentId");
            m.MapRightKey("ChildId");
        });
```

Here is the breeze metadata for it:

name": "Product",
"customannotation:ClrType": "Product, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
"key": {

```
"propertyRef": {
    "name": "Id"
}
```

},
"property": [
 ...
],
"navigationProperty": [

```
{
    "name": "PackContents",
    "relationship": "Self.Product_PackContents",
    "fromRole": "Product_PackContents_Source",
    "toRole": "Product_PackContents_Target"
},
{
    "name": "PackParents",
    "relationship": "Self.Product_PackContents",
    "fromRole": "Product_PackContents_Target",
    "toRole": "Product_PackContents_Source"
}, ... removed
```

when I put this into a breeze controller lookups query I get the following schema (and where appropriate PackContents has child product objects)

"Products": [
    {
        "$id": "6",
        "$type": "Core.Product, Core",
        "PackContents": [ ],
        "PackParents": [ ],
    ... others removed
    }]

however when I do a console.log on the client the arrays of PackContents and PackParents do not appear in the json object whereas other navigation properties do:

```
_$typeName: "Product:#Core",
_backingStore: Object { id=7, productTypeId=1, description="Vaillant 624", more...},
_pendingBackingStores: [],
brand: null,    
code: null,
companyProducts: [],    
cost: 750,
description: "Vaillant 624",
entityAspect: Object { entity={...}, entityGroup={...}, entityManager={...}, more...},
entityType: Product:#Core { shortName="Product", namespace="Core", isAbstract=false, more...},  
id: 7,
// I am expecting to see Pack Contents and pack parents here
quoteMeasureProducts: [],
quoteProducts: [],
```

Does anyone know why the navigation property companyProducts would be created and not PackContents or PackParents? What can I do to ensure these are created on the client?

Edit:

On advice I created a separate join table:

```
public class ProductRelationship : BaseEntityInt
{

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Product Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Child { get; set; }
}
```

with config:

```
        HasRequired(a => a.Child).WithMany(b => b.PackParents).HasForeignKey(c => c.ChildId);
        HasRequired(a => a.Parent).WithMany(b => b.PackContents).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

which is referenced in the product class thus:

```
    public virtual ICollection<ProductRelationship> PackContents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductRelationship> PackParents { get; set; }
```

So I now have the navigation properties but they are still not populated and are all empty arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze doesn't yet support many-to-many navigation properties - you'll need to have a separate entity for the join table, I'm afraid.

See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/presenting-many-many

Comment: Thanks for this. Is this the reason packContents and packParents are not present, because there are other navigation properties which aren't present that I can't account for either?

Comment: The reason I couldn't see the other properties was because my Get method was returning an IEnumerable<Product> and a projection of the same as well. I used an IQueryable to get around this and removed the projection. It doesn't seem to like projections

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add support for many to many navigational properties.

Go to breeze javascript
Find the function named unwrapInstance

```
function unwrapInstance(structObj, transformFn)
```

replace it with this

```
function unwrapInstance(structObj, transformFn) {
      if (!structObj.unwrapped) {
          structObj.unwrapped = true;
          var rawObject = {};
          var stype = structObj.entityType || structObj.complexType;
          var serializerFn = getSerializerFn(stype);
          var unmapped = {};
          stype.dataProperties.forEach(function (dp) {
              if (dp.isComplexProperty) {
                  rawObject[dp.nameOnServer] = __map(structObj.getProperty(dp.name), function (co) {
                      if (!co.unwrapped) {
                          return unwrapInstance(co, transformFn);
                      }
                  });
              } else {
                  var val = structObj.getProperty(dp.name);
                  val = transformFn ? transformFn(dp, val) : val;
                  if (val === undefined) return;
                  val = serializerFn ? serializerFn(dp, val) : val;
                  if (val !== undefined) {
                      if (dp.isUnmapped) {
                          unmapped[dp.nameOnServer] = __toJSONSafe(val);
                      } else {
                          rawObject[dp.nameOnServer] = val;
                      }
                  }
              }
          });
          stype.navigationProperties.forEach(function (dp) {
              rawObject[dp.nameOnServer] = __map(structObj.getProperty(dp.name), function (co) {
                  if (!co.unwrapped) {
                      return unwrapInstance(co, transformFn);
                  }
              });
          });

          if (!__isEmpty(unmapped)) {
              rawObject.__unmapped = unmapped;
          }
          return rawObject;
      }
  }
```

Comment: I've added a breeze suggestion for this. https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6790261-support-for-collections-of-navigational-properties please vote if you think this is a good solution for navigational properties